# Split a string but a delimiter, only outside of [...] pair

Tags: c#, split

How can i split a string, using ";" as a delimiter but only when this delimiter is NOT inside any [...].
e.g

```
[a;b]c;d[e;f]  => <0>[a;b]c  <1>d[e;f]
a;b;c[e;f;g]   => <0>a <1>b <2>c[e;f;g]
abcd[e;f]      => <0>abcd[e;f]
```

Comment: You have to write a parser for this

Comment: I recommend to use Regex

Comment: Thanks, but this is my question, how do I split it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex approach which uses a negative lookahead to assert that only semicolons which are not nested inside `[...]` are used for splitting:

```
string input = "[a;b]c;d[e;f]";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, @";(?![^\[]*\])"); 
foreach (string part in parts)  
{
   Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

This prints:

```
[a;b]c
d[e;f]
```

Here is an explanation of the regex used:

```
;             match a semicolon
(?![^\[]*\])  provided that we can look ahead and confirm that we CANNOT hit a closing ]
              without first also hitting an opening [
```

If the negative lookahead asserts, then it means that the semicolon is not inside `[...]`.  Note that my answer assumes that you would never have *nested* brackets.  If you could have that, you should move away from regex and instead consider writing a simple parser.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will handle the nested brackets and works faster than regular expression. I have run 100000 iterations for the following code and received an elapsed time of 322ms vs 1116ms for code using RegExp.Split().

```
        List<string> list_OutputStr = new List<string>();
        int i_NestedBracketsCount = 0;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char ch in s_InputStr)
        {
            if (ch.Equals(';') && i_NestedBracketsCount == 0) { list_OutputStr.Add(sb.ToString()); sb.Clear(); continue; }
            else if (ch.Equals('[')) i_NestedBracketsCount++;
            else if (ch.Equals(']')) i_NestedBracketsCount--;
            sb.Append(ch);
        }
        if (sb.Length > 0) list_OutputStr.Add(sb.ToString());

        foreach (string str in list_OutputStr)
            Console.Write(str + "\t");
```